# Float line color for selected menu item

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, menu

I am using float line menu for my wordpress site, I got [THIS FAR](http://jsfiddle.net/DSKBv/) with some help.

Now my question is how can I make the selected nav float line to be the same color as when you hover over the menu item? At this moment as soon as the mouse is off, it changes into default red.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

When Menu 1 seleceted (after the click), the float line color should be `#0f0`

Menu 2 selected - `#ee0`

Menu3 selected - `#05f`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding  `var currentSelected;` above `var sse1 = function () {` and adding `currentSelected=k;` to the block below

```
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (url.indexOf(a[i].href.toLowerCase()) != -1 && a[i].href.length > nLength) {
                k = i;
                nLength = a[i].href.length;
            }
        }
```

Will push the index of the current selected list to `currentSelected`.

So use it in your `customHandleMenu` function

```
var navigations=[
/* Nav 1 style */
{floatColor: '#0f0',
borderColor: '#0f0'},
/* Nav 2 style */
{floatColor: '#ee0',
borderColor: '#ee0'},
/* Nav 3 style */
{floatColor: '#05f',
borderColor: '#05f'},
];

function customHandleMenu() {
  // get nav selector
  var nav = $('#sses1 > ul');

  // get float line selector
  var floatLine = $('.highlight'); // .hightlight must exist at this point

  // get colors for the current page
  var defaultBGcolor = navigations[currentSelected]["borderColor"];
  var defaultBorderColor = navigations[currentSelected]["borderColor"];
  var defaultNavBorderColor = navigations[currentSelected]["borderColor"];
  // change background-color and border-color on mouseenter event

  $('.nav-item-1').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      setColors({
        floatColor: navigations[0]["floatColor"],
        borderColor: navigations[0]["borderColor"]
      });
    }
  });

  $('.nav-item-2').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      setColors({
        floatColor: navigations[1]["floatColor"],
        borderColor: navigations[1]["borderColor"]
      });
    }
  });

  $('.nav-item-3').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      setColors({
        floatColor: navigations[2]["floatColor"],
        borderColor: navigations[2]["borderColor"]
      });
    }
  }); 

    /*
       ...
    */

    // put back default colors on the mouseleave event
    $('#sses1 > ul > li').on({
        mouseleave: function() {
          setColors({floatColor:defaultBGcolor, borderColor:defaultNavBorderColor});
        }
    });
          setColors({floatColor:defaultBGcolor, borderColor:defaultNavBorderColor});

    function setColors(args) {
        if (typeof args.floatColor != "undefined") {
            floatLine.css('background-color', args.floatColor);
        }

        if (typeof args.borderColor != "undefined") {
            floatLine.css('border-color', args.borderColor);
            nav.css('border-bottom-color', args.borderColor);
        }
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DSKBv/1/show/?menu=1&skin=2&p=Javascript-Menus) | [Demo source](http://jsfiddle.net/DSKBv/1/)

To prevent the Float Line from animating onload, just follow the instructions commented inside the code

```
//slip.style.left = items[k].offsetLeft + "px";
sse1.move(items[k]); //comment out this line and uncomment the line above to disable initial animation
```

To create:

```
slip.style.left = items[k].offsetLeft + "px";
// sse1.move(items[k]); comment out this line and uncomment the line above to disable initial animation.
```

Also, you can **optionally** add

```
$('#sses1 li, #sses1 a').on('click',function(){ 
  $('#sses1, #sses1 ul, #sses1 li, #sses1 a').unbind("mouseout");
  $('#sses1, #sses1 ul, #sses1 li, #sses1 a').unbind("mouseleave");
  $('#sses1, #sses1 ul, #sses1 li, #sses1 a').unbind("mouseenter");
  $('#sses1, #sses1 ul, #sses1 li, #sses1 a').unbind("mousein");
  $('#sses1, #sses1 ul, #sses1 li, #sses1 a').unbind("mouseover");
  sse1={};
});
```

To your `customhandlemenu` function, to fully disable any unwanted animations while the page prepares to load.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DSKBv/24/show/?menu=1&skin=2&p=Javascript-Menus) | [Demo source](http://jsfiddle.net/DSKBv/24/)

Comment: Hi Extramonster, thanks very much for your help, it looks great. Just one little question, when menu item 1 is selected, then your mouse hovers to menu3 and click menu 3, for a second or two you can see the float line is going back to menu 1 and then go to menu 3 again. Is there any way to avoid this extra transaction? I mean when you hover on one menu item and click, the float line just stays underneath the menu item selected rather than going back to the previous one and then back again to the selected one? Thanks heaps!

Comment: Thank you Extramonster, you are a javascript legend. I will have to look into what you've done more detailly before I understand it all. One last question, can I still keep the float line animated (move left and right once, then stay still) after the click? At this moment it stays still after the click on each menu. How do I achieve it please? Thank you very much!

Comment: Remove the optional code: http://jsfiddle.net/DSKBv/26/show/?menu=1&skin=2&p=Javascript-Menus http://jsfiddle.net/DSKBv/26/

Comment: Thanks Monster, I must be confusing you, it looks like the float line goes back to the previous selected menu item again and then back to the new selected menu item. Can we make the float line stays under the new selected menu all the way? So what I mean is that the float line animates left and right once (underneath the hovered menu item only) when you hover the item, and the float line moves left and right once again (underneath the clicked menu item only)after the click function (but no going back and forth with the previous selected item)? thank you so much.